# Conditionally use material-ui default prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a `StepLabel` component in material ui. Depending on the props passed to the parent, I may want to change the `icon` prop of the StepLabel:

```js
interface Props {
  customClasses?: ClassNameMap;
  customIcon?: ReactNode;
}

const MyStepComponent = (props: Props) => {

  const { customClasses, customIcon } = props

  return (
    <Stepper {...stepperProps}>
      <Step
        icon={
          customIcon
            ? React.cloneElement(customIcon as React.ReactElement, {
                className: customClasses?.stepIcon
              })
            : null
          }
        {...otherStepProps}
      />
    </Stepper>
  )

}
```

So in this scenario, if a `customIcon` is passed to `MyStepComponent` it will render that icon instead of the default, and if `customClasses` is passed as well, it will apply some of those custom classes to that icon.  Great.

But in the event that `customIcon` is *not* passed, I would like for the `Step` component to just use its default icon (which is the blue circle with the step number in it).  However, in my code, it does not render the default icon, it renders `null`.

How can I tell the `Step` to use my `customIcon` if it exists, but if not, use the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the customIcon is truthy then the first if will be triggered and the component with the custom icon will be rendered.

```js
 const MyStepComponent = (props: Props) => {

      const { customClasses, customIcon } = props
      
      if (customIcon) {
        return (
            <Stepper {...stepperProps}>
          <Step
            icon={ React.cloneElement(customIcon as React.ReactElement, {
                    className: customClasses?.stepIcon
                  })
              }
            {...otherStepProps}
          />
        </Stepper>
        )
      }

      return (
        <Stepper {...stepperProps}>
          <Step
            icon={defaultIcon}
            {...otherStepProps}
          />
        </Stepper>
      )

    }
```